# Box A has 3 red and 7 white balls

Tags: probability

Box A has 3 red and 7 white balls. Box B has 5 red and 1 blue ball. A random ball is chosen from box A and placed into box B, and then one is chosen from box B. Find the probability that 
a) both balls are red
b) the second ball is red 
c) the first ball is red, given that the second ball is blue

I got 18/70 for question a and 1/2 for question b, but I'm not sure how to do C. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

For part c you need to use conditional probability:

$$P(First=red \;| \;Second=blue)$$  $$=\frac{P(First=Red) \; P(Second=blue)}{P(Second=blue)}$$  $$=\frac{\frac{3}{10}\frac{1}{7}}{\frac{1}{7}}$$
$$=\frac{3}{10}$$

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the second ball is blue, doesn't change the probabilities for the first ball.

Comment: So I would use the same method, and solve this by finding the probability that the first ball is red, and then the probability that the second ball is blue, and then multiplying them together?

Comment: @user148748 Basically yes. But be very carefull! Before continuing answer me this. After picking a red ball from box A, what is the probability of choosing a red ball from box B???

Comment: 1/7. I just read pwerth's comment, and I think that it makes sense to use the conditional probability formula. So then that would give 3/10.

Comment: Correct. But I was hoping you would see that the chanses of the second ball being blue are exactly one, since you are told that it is blue in the question. The mathematical explanation can be seen in pwerth's furmula indeed.

Comment: Ohh I understand now. Thank you!